# Specifying quadratic models for D-optimal designs in AlgDesign - quad function not found

Tags: r, experimental-design

I need to optimize a production process by way of adjusting a total of 6 factors, all of them numerical variables with 3 levels. I expect the responses to be related to both the main effects and their quadratic terms, and I expect some of the second order interactions (3 of them, to be precise) to have an effect as well.

Based on this, I figured out I would use AlgDesign and the `OptFederov` function to get a D-optimal design.

I created the corresponding full factorial design matrix and formulated the model I want to attempt to fit to the data:

```
df <- gen.factorial(levels = 3, nVars = 6, varNames = LETTERS[1:6])

mod <- formula('~ A + A^2 + B + B^2 + C + C^2 + D + D^2 + E + E^2 + F + F^2 + + A:C + A:D + C:E + C:F + E*F')
```

Using `OptFedorov` I get:

```
design1 <- optFederov(frml = mod, data = df, nullify = 1)

unique(design1$design$A)
[1] -1  1
```

The same thing applies to all variables, that is, `OptFedorov` seems to only consider the extreme levels, not the mid point of each factor which, as far as I understand it, would not allow me to fit a quadratic function at all.

Since the documentation for AlgDesign suggests to use the `quad()` function for models with quadratic terms, I tried just that, and:

```
mod2 <- formula('~A + B + C + D + E + F + + A:C + A:D + C:E + C:F + E:F')

design2 <- optFederov(frml = quad(mod2), data = df, nullify = 1)

Error in quad(mod2) : could not find function "quad"
```

Using `expand.formula()` doesn't help either:

```
expand.formula(~.2, colnames(variables2))
~0.2
```

All the documentation I read makes use of the `quad()` function or some variation of the dot notation in the formula. So, am I missing something with the formulation of the model, or am I getting lost in localization or incompatible versions of R?

For reference the output of `sessionInfo()` is>

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Super-Duper 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rejection 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_3.1.7      AlgDesign_1.2.1   agricolae_1.3-5   FrF2_2.3          DoE.base_1.2-2   
[6] conf.design_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3         vcd_1.4-11           lattice_0.20-45      zoo_1.8-10           digest_0.6.29       
 [6] lmtest_0.9-40        utf8_1.2.2           gmp_0.7-1            mime_0.12            R6_2.5.1            
[11] labelled_2.10.0      evaluate_0.15        highr_0.9            pillar_1.7.0         Rdpack_2.4          
[16] rlang_1.0.2          rstudioapi_0.13      minqa_1.2.4          miniUI_0.1.1.1       nloptr_2.0.3        
[21] Matrix_1.4-1         combinat_0.0-8       mathjaxr_1.6-0       splines_4.2.0        partitions_1.10-7   
[26] lme4_1.1-29          polynom_1.4-1        stringr_1.4.0        questionr_0.7.7      numbers_0.8-5       
[31] igraph_1.4.2         shiny_1.7.1          compiler_4.2.0       httpuv_1.6.5         xfun_0.31           
[36] pkgconfig_2.0.3      htmltools_0.5.2      tidyselect_1.1.2     fansi_1.0.3          crayon_1.5.1        
[41] dplyr_1.0.9          later_1.3.0          MASS_7.3-56          rbibutils_2.2.13     nlme_3.1-157        
[46] xtable_1.8-4         lifecycle_1.0.1      magrittr_2.0.1       stringi_1.7.3        cli_3.3.0           
[51] promises_1.2.0.1     scatterplot3d_0.3-41 ellipsis_0.3.2       generics_0.1.2       vctrs_0.4.1         
[56] boot_1.3-28          klaR_1.7-1           tools_4.2.0          forcats_0.5.1        glue_1.6.2          
[61] purrr_0.3.4          sfsmisc_1.1-15       hms_1.1.1            fastmap_1.1.0        colorspace_2.0-3    
[66] cluster_2.1.3        knitr_1.39           haven_2.5.0
```

Comment: Does the documentation you refer to specify which package the `quad()` function is coming from? The pracma package perhaps?

Comment: Oh thank you, you're right! It was the pracma package. There is no mention of it in the help pages for either the OptFedorov or the expand.formula functions. And there is no mention of it in the vignette for the AlgDesign package either (just did a text search in it, and nope, no match).